# Show current time (EST)

Tags: vba, excel, datetime, userform

I created a UserForm that contains a textbox that will show the current time in EST. The only problem is, the time that's reflecting is of course the current time in our country so I want to convert it in EST, which is `- 12:00` from our time.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    txtDate.Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you also add the expected output and what you're actually seeing?

Comment: *"which is - 12:00"* - That assumes that neither your time zone nor Eastern time changes for daylight saving time.  You didn't state your time zone, but US Eastern Time does indeed change, as it just did this past weekend.

Comment: Sorry im using UTC+08:00, so I think it should now be -13:00.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `TimeValue` function like this :

```
txtDate.Value = Format(Now - TimeValue("12:00:00"), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 2):

A more complicated way than R3uK but I've always preferred using `TimeSerial()` and `DateSerial()` to get my exact criteria setup (especially when you need to modify multiple parts of the Time).

```
Sub TimeToEST()

Dim ESTHour As Integer
If Hour(Now) - 12 < 0 Then
    ESTHour = 24 + Hour(Now) - 12
Else
    ESTHour = Hour(Now) - 12
End If

txtDate.Value = TimeSerial(ESTHour, Minute(Now), Second(Now))

End Sub
```

To show just the current date in EST:

```
Sub DateToEST()

Dim ESTDate As Date
If Hour(Now) < 12 And Day(Now) = 1 Then
    ESTDate = Now - TimeValue("12:00:00")
ElseIf Hour(Now) < 12 Then
    ESTDate = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now) - 1)
Else
    ESTDate = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
End If

txtDate.Value = ESTDate

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Chrismas, What if i only want the date to show?. Not the time

Comment: @user5500328 Updated, but much more complicated than R3uk's entry.

Comment: The time VBA is running but I'm showing a syntax error when I changed the VBA. Its highlighting this part of the VBA Else If Hour(Now) < 12 Then

Comment: @user5500328 My bad, should be no space between Else and If... just `ElseIf`

Answer (score 0):

Its far simpler if you want to use it in a formula.
Use the NOW() function, and then subtract the difference using TIME function.

For example, I am in a timezone which is 9:30 hrs ahead of EST.
So the get EST time, I'll take the current date-time in my timezone using NOW(), and then subtract 9 hrs 30 minutes from it using the following formula.

=NOW()-TIME(9,30,0)

Enjoy!

Comment: This just adds a fixed offset, which is not sufficient for converting to a different timezone (due to daylight savings).  Did you read the comments under the question?

Comment: My answer was to the original question which said "which is - 12:00 from our time" i.e. fixed time deduction. DST changes will have to be taken care of by changing the arguments in the TIME function (Twice a year exercise)